# CSS layout width fixed width and fluid right column

Tags: css, layout, fluid-layout, fluid

I have a fixed with container, lets say 1120px. Inside this container, i have a left sidebar which is 400px, and i need a right sidebar which is expanding from the container and touching the right side of the screen. Here is an image explaining the layout i want:

[image: Explaining the issue]

This is the progress i made so far: http://jsfiddle.net/UvxK8/

```
#wrapper {
    background:#f0f0f0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#wrapper .left {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    height:600px;
    background:#333;
}

#wrapper .right {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:100px;
    height: 650px;
    background: green;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

Obviously its not good, because the right sidebar is too wide and a horizontal scrollbar appears.

Answer (score 0):

The image you've used doesn't match your desicription of what you want; I think maybe you're looking at this the wrong way. If the right sidebar spills beyond the container, what's the point of the fixed width container at all?

From your image, it looks like what you want is...

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"><h1>Content here.</h1></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="container-left">
        <p>Content here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container-right">
        <p>Content here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {width:1120px;}
#container {width:100%; min-width:100%;}
#container-left {width:400px; float:left; }
#container-right {width:100%; min-width:100%;}
```

This will create the image illustration you've used. jFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4JNX2/

Comment: according to this container-right will create below container-left @BFDatabaseAdmin

Comment: Notice that the image is wider that the container, that means the whole image is the body, and the container is centred inside the body. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @AtalShrivastava - Sorry, couple of errors in my CSS. Corrected now, with jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks, but the container should be centered inside the body. Also, your updated example still generates a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @passatgt - Yes, it will generate a horizontal scroll becuase the jsFiddle window is less than 1120px wide...

Comment: Still not what i want. The container needs to be fixed, with margin:0 auto;

Comment: you can add overflow-x:hidden, even if it is a fluid container. Why not you are using flexbox @passatgt

Comment: with overflow hidden, if i have text in the right column, the right side will be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative to your wrapper. try this

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper
{width:1120px;
background:#096;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}

#wrapper #left {
width:10%;
float:left;
height:600px;
background:#333;
}

#wrapper #right {
position:absolute;
margin-left:10%;
height: 650px;
background: green;
min-width:95%;
}
```

Comment: A horizintal scrollbar still appears based on the browser width, so this is not a good solution.

Comment: i have edited my answer check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2R7S/). this is for fixed 1120px container. if you are looking for responsive on this then you need to add media queries